# count all lines of code of an entire project group

Tags: delphi

Never thought about it before but is there an easy way to count all lines of code in a project? You can see how many lines of code there are in a single form but if you have hundreds its not an easy task.

Does RAD Studio have a feature to count the number of lines in your project?

Comment: You can try CnPack - Source Statistics if you use it. It is easier and more accurate, also it doesn't count other libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way. You can just build a project and you'll see total number of compiled lines. It's funny sometimes... say, when I built a release with exactly 666'666 total.

Make sure that 'Automatically close on successful compile' is unchecked otherwise the compile window may disappear too quickly. Or look under Project/Info right after the build.

Comment: If you want a full line count, however, you have to be sure to clean before compiling.  That dialog only shows the number of lines the compiler needed to compile - if your output directory already has compiled .dcu files whose source .pas files have not been modified since the last compile it will not bother to recompile them.

Comment: @J... That's with *compile*, not with *build*.

Comment: That will count also empty lines. Maybe this is better: https://nloc.sourceforge.net